# Сложный фильтр по таблице

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, обработка-данных

Существует вот такой DF:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
      route  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
0       108   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1       108   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2       108   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
3       121   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
4       110   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
5       110   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

Необходимо найти только те `route`, которые не работают по выходным - `sa = 0` и `su = 0`. Проблема в том, что маршруты дублируются с разными вариантами расписания и получается, что если задавать условие суб=0, вс=0, то результат уберет дубликаты в которых суб=1 и вс=1.

Например маршрут 110 содержит два поля, по которому ясно, что он ходит каждый день и он не нужен. Проблему усложняет то, что попадаются маршруты с 3 вариантами, которые также не нужны.

Должно получиться вот это:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
      route  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
3       121   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

Comment: Если ответ вам подошёл - отметьте его, как правильный специальной галочкой. Если же нет, то дайте комментарий к ответу, что не так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вам достаточно просуммировать значения в каждой группе, получив одну строку для каждого `route_id` и оставить только те строки для которых сумма значений за субботу и воскресенье равна нулю. Причем рабочие дни недели можно вовсе не рассматривать в решении.

Пример данных:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
   route_id  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
0       108   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1       108   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2       108   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
3       121   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
4       110   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
5       110   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

решение:

```
res = df.groupby("route_id").filter(lambda x: x[["Sa", "Su"]].sum().sum() == 0)
```

результат:

```
In [118]: res
Out[118]: 
   route_id  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  Su
3       121   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

PS прошу обратить внимание и учесть на будущее, что для того чтобы привести воспроизводимый пример данных часто достаточно небольшого "синтетического" примера.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это работает!

Про данные и пример я учту на будущее